# ASP.NET code in Page_Load not invoked on Post Back

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple web application where I am adding some data to the database using Entity Framework and then populating it in a drop down list, from which I can select the tuple I wish to delete. The problem I am facing is that when I add a new record, the dropdown list does not get populated. I have to reload the page again to see that. Here is the code behind for the Page_Load method

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int token = Int32.Parse(Request.Cookies["EmcLabs"]["authToken"]);
        EMCLabCustomerDataEntities context = new EMCLabCustomerDataEntities();
        User u = new User();
        u = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Token == token);
        lblJumboUsername.Text = u.Name;
        lblJumboPost.Text = u.Post;
        context.Dispose();
        InitializePage();                                   
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Response.Cookies["EmcLabs"].Expires = DateTime.Now;
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }

}
public void InitializePage()
{
    EMCLabCustomerDataEntities context = new EMCLabCustomerDataEntities();
    User usr = new User();
    usr = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == lblJumboUsername.Text);
    if (usr.IsAdmin != 1)
    {
        divAdmin.Visible = false;
    }     
    //Users
    try
    {
        ddlUserList.DataSource = (from x in context.Users
                                  where x.Name != lblJumboUsername.Text
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      x.Name,
                                      x.Id
                                  }).ToList();
        ddlUserList.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddlUserList.DataValueField = "Id";
        ddlUserList.DataBind();
        ddlUserList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select User", "default"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        divMessages.Attributes.Add("class", "alert alert-danger");
        lblMessage.Text += ex.Message;
    }
}
```

The following the the code that I have to add and delete the records.

```
rotected void btnAddUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        User u = new User();
        u.Email = txtEmail.Text.Trim();
        u.Name = txtName.Text.Trim();
        u.Password = txtRandomPass.Text;
        u.Post = txtPost.Text.Trim();
        u.Token = 0;
        if (chkAdmin.Checked == true)
        {
            u.IsAdmin = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            u.IsAdmin = 0;
        }
        EMCLabCustomerDataEntities context = new EMCLabCustomerDataEntities();
        if (true)
        {

        }
        context.Users.Add(u);
        context.SaveChanges();
        divMessages.Attributes.Add("class", "alert alert-success");
        lblMessage.Text = "New user added successfully.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        divMessages.Attributes.Add("class", "alert alert-danger");
        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
    }

}

protected void btnDeluser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkConfirmDelete.Checked == true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ddlUserList.SelectedItem.Value != "default")
            {
                EMCLabCustomerDataEntities context = new EMCLabCustomerDataEntities();
                User u = context.Users.Single(x => x.Name == ddlUserList.SelectedItem.Text);
                context.Users.Remove(u);
                context.SaveChanges();
                divMessages.Attributes.Add("class", "alert alert-success");
                lblMessage.Text = "User deleted successfully.";
            }
            else
            {
                divMessages.Attributes.Add("class", "alert alert-warning");
                lblMessage.Text = "Select an user to remove first.";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            divMessages.Attributes.Add("class", "alert alert-danger");
            lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        divMessages.Attributes.Add("class", "alert alert-warning");
        lblMessage.Text = "Confirm before deleting.";
    }
}
```

Comment: It is must to reload the page. If you want to populate single control without reloading the whole page, then use AJAX. Just wrap the **DropDownList** with AJAX.

Comment: If I reload the page, then is there any way to show a message that the addition or deletion has succeeded without using query links?

Comment: You can use a label for that and **label.Text="Added"** on reload.

Comment: I am already using a label for that. But once the page refreshes after that, the label will be gone. It is not persistent. You can see that I have used an lblMessage.Text for it.

Comment: You should adjust your code based on [Page Life Cycle Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) of web forms. You can see that your button's click event is handled _after_ `Load` (which is also why you see your expected result if you reload). So adjust the binding call to accommodate both initial load and subsequent (postback) events. Hth.

Comment: It is fixed by rebinding the data with the control after saving changes to the context.